# Increasing performance for search pandas df, Count occurrences of starting string grouped by unique identifier

Tags: python, pandas, loops, search

Current dataframe is as follows:

```
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', delimiter=',')

print(df)
idx   uniqueID      String 

0        1           'hello'
1        1           'goodbye'
2        1           'happy'
3        2           'hello'
4        2           'happy'
5        3           'goodbye' 
6        3           'hello'
7        3           'hello'
8        4           'goodbye'
9        5           'goodbye'
```

Expected Output:

```
{ 'hello': 2, 'goodbye' : 3} 
Where hello was counted by idx 0 & 3, and goodbye was counted by idx 5 & 8 & 9. 
In the actual dataset there are more than two starting strings. 



I'm thinking of potentially using pandas .groupby() && .where(), 
to filter out for the first time a uniqueId occurs, then group 
by the string? Not entirely sure.
```

Question: **How do I get the counts of the 'starting string', only when uniqueID is occurring for the first time with increased performance.**

Thus far, I'm doing with a simple for loop of the data and checking with if/else statements. But this is incredibly slow with a large dataframe.

I'm curious if there are any functions built in pandas, or another library out there, that would reduce the overall time it takes.

Comment: Have you tried using the [searchsorted function](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.searchsorted.html)?

Comment: @BenGrossmann I'm not familiar with this function, but the examples given on the documentation seem not super applicable. How were you thinking of using it?

Comment: It's not possible to do this faster than O(N) without sorted data, because there's no way to know whether a given row contains a `hello` or a `goodbye` without looking at it (we can't exclude it a priori), therefore we must look at every row to do the calculation, and there are O(N) rows. If your question is about constant-factor performance improvements, please don't abuse the terminology.

Comment: Got it. @KarlKnechtel , didn't intend to 'abuse the terminology', just newer to this and in essence was looking for a faster way. Was just unsure how to go about it, apologies.

Comment: " but the examples given on the documentation seem not super applicable. How were you thinking of using it?" It would be applicable if the data were sorted, and it would be O(lg N). By searching for both "sides" of a value in the sorted data, you can infer how many copies there are of that value.

Comment: Actually, I don't think I understand the requirement. Why is the expected result `{ 'hello': 2, 'goodbye' : 3}`? I see 4 copies of each. And what does the `uniqueID` column have to do with the problem?

Comment: Essentially, want to count the number of times a string was present at the first occurrence of a uniqueID. So in the example, the counts of 'hello' and 'goodbye', are counted at idx 0/3 & 5/8/9, respectively. Does this make sense? @KarlKnechtel

Comment: Ah, so select the first row in each ID group, and then apply the counting technique.

Comment: @Ev0 Sorry, I had misread the question

Comment: Yep! @KarlKnechtel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Achieving better than O(N) is not possible.

You can `drop_duplicates`, then `value_counts`:

```
out = df.drop_duplicates('uniqueID')['String'].value_counts()
```

output:

```
goodbye    3
hello      2
Name: String, dtype: int64
```

As dictionary:

```
df.drop_duplicates('uniqueID')['String'].value_counts().to_dict()
```

output: `{'goodbye': 3, 'hello': 2}`